# Is there any advantage to using BytesIO with markdown instead of open / read in Python?

Tags: python, markdown, stringio

Considering the following code:

```
from markdown import markdown

f = open('myfile.md', 'r')
html_text = markdown(f.read())
f.close()
```

Is there any speed advantage or disadvantage to using io.BytesIO and markdownFromFile? Or is it a wash?

```
from markdown import markdownFromFile
from io import BytesIO

s = BytesIO()
markdownFromFile(input='myfile.md', output=s)
html_text = s.getvalue()
s.close()
```

Thanks in advance for any information.

Comment: Did you benchmark it?

Comment: I'm going to once I'm in the office tomorrow; running it under a Vagrant box on a laptop at home doesn't seem like a good sandbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be best if you benchmark it yourself, but just from the looks of it I don't see any advantage of using `BytesIO`. Instead of reading the file and parsing it directly into a string, you'd be first reading and processing it into a `BytesIO` object and then using `BytesIO.getvalue` to get the string you need.

The former also is easier to read. Could be made even simpler with:

```
with open('myfile.md', 'r') as f:
    html_text = markdown(f.read())
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll benchmark tomorrow for my own edification, but your answer makes complete sense.

Comment: As the developer of Python-Markdown, I would completely agree with this answer with one exception: be careful, you appear to think you are working with bytes; however the Markdown library it all Unicode (both in and out). Of course ASCII input won't be a problem, but anything else will if you don't account for that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and all of your work on the excellent library, Waylan - much appreciated.